# eleasticsearch not working with Rails in production in EC2 cent os instalce in production with Nginx

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using: Ruby version 2.4.0 & Rails 5.2.3, aws Ec2 instance with CentOS 7 
Application is using searchkiq gem for elasticsearch.

My Models which are using searchkiq as:

```
class ThreeDGarment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :three_d_model_id, :category_id, :pieces, :body, :fabric, :total_length, :chest, :waist, :hip, presence: true
  has_many :three_d_garment_images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tukabank_order_items, as: :itemable
  has_one :garment_efm
  has_one :garment_edm
  has_one :garment_pattern
  belongs_to :three_d_model
  belongs_to :category
  mount_uploader :thumbnail, ThreeDGarmentThumbnailUploader
  validates_presence_of :thumbnail

  ## To add the functionality of elastic search
  searchkick

  ## parameters `to be searched by elastic search
  def search_data
    {
        category: category.try(:name),
        chest: chest,
        total_length: total_length,
        waist: waist,
        hip: hip,
        body: body,
    }
  end
end
```

when I reindex my Model ThreeDGarment in the rails console in production model it gives the following error:

```
2.4.0 :014 > ThreeDGarment.reindex
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:
 [three_d_garment : {_routing={}, dynamic_templates=[
 {string_template={mapping={ignore_above=30000, type=keyword,
 fields={analyzed={analyzer=searchkick_index, index=true, type=text}}},
 match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}], properties={}}]"}],
 "type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping
 [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:
 [three_d_garment : {_routing={}, dynamic_templates=
 [{string_template={mapping={ignore_above=30000, type=keyword,
 fields={analyzed={analyzer=searchkick_index, index=true, type=text}}},
 match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}], properties={}}]",
 "caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
 "reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: 
 [three_d_garment : {_routing={}, dynamic_templates=
 [{string_template={mapping={ignore_above=30000, type=keyword,
 fields={analyzed={analyzer=searchkick_index, index=true, type=text}}},
 match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}], properties={}}]"}},"status":400}
```

I am running elastic search server: Elasticsearch repository for 7.x packages and is running at

Answer (score 0):

Remove the older version of searchkiq gem and update it to the following version in Gemfile:

```
gem 'searchkick', '~> 4.01'
```

this versionworks with elasticsearch 7.x

for `gem 'searchkick', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.2'`
this works with `elasticseatch 6.x`